# Change disclosure button arrow color

Tags: swiftui

I am creating a scrollView with a code like this:

```
ScrollView {
  ForEach(items) { item in
    VStack {
      DisclosureGroup {
        SubElements()
      }
      label: {
        DisplayItem(item)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

One thing I don't like about this is the chevron color. I want it black.

How do I change that?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the chevron color with adding `.accentColor` after your `DisclosureGroup`.

Accent color is a color that represents the system or application accent color. See the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/familycontrols/familyactivityiconview/accentcolor(_:))

---

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For your first issue it is probably down to padding that is stopping the indicator from being inset enough. As you haven't included all your code, it's difficult to tell where to put it but on your ScrollView should be enough.

For the color of the indicator, you can just use the `accentColor` modifier, and set the color that you want.

Here is a very simple example.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
                DisclosureGroup(
                    content: { Text("Content") },
                    label: { Text("Label") }
                )
                .accentColor(.black)
            }
        }.padding(.horizontal, 30)
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: Totally counter intuitive. I tried tint first. This will be there in iOS15, unsure if this will do the trick as well, but it works with accentColor!

Answer (score 2):

[`accentColor(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/familycontrols/familyactivityiconview/accentcolor(_:)) mentioned in all answers so far will be or is already deprecated. Use [`tint(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/tint(_:)-23xyq) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change the color of content with `foregroundColor` and color of the arrow with `accentColor`:

```
DisclosureGroup {
  HStack {
    Text(faqElement.answer)
      .adaptiveFont(size: 14, family: .app, style: .regular)
      .foregroundColor(Color.App.Dynamic.Gray.value_900) // <-- Color of the text in content
    Spacer()
  }
  .padding(.vertical)
} label: {
  HStack {
    Text(faqElement.question)
      .adaptiveFont(size: 20, family: .app, style: .regular)
      .foregroundColor(Color.App.Dynamic.Gray.value_900) // <-- Color of the label
    Spacer()
  }
   .frame(height: 34)
}
.accentColor(Color.App.Static.Green.value_700) // <-- Color of the arrow
```

[image]